# running logcat in background from adb

Tags: android, linux, shell, adb, logcat

i'm trying send a command through adb to an android device in order to trigger logcat recording to a file on the device.
to do so, i trigger the command:

> `adb shell "logcat > /sdcard/logcat.log"`

so far so good, but the thing is that i need the command to run in the background, and not to keep an open connection to the PC. 
meaning, that if i send a command and disconnect the usb cable, i want to have the logcat recording keep running in the background. 
if i execute

> $ adb shell
>
> $ logcat > /sdcard/logcat.log &

I can safely disconnect the USB cable, and the recording will keep on going. 
however, if i execute the command from outside of the shell as follows:

```
adb shell "logcat > /sdcard/logcat.log &"
```

i get a file in `/sdcard` called `logcat.log` which weights 0 bytes.
after trying several varieations i tried placing a script file with the command
"`logcat > /sdcard/logcat.log &`" in /sdcard called /logcatScript.log
and running it from outside of the shell using

> adb shell "sh /sdcard/logcatScript.log"

but the same 0 byte file is being created.

The device is not rooted, and should not be, so busyBox is not an option.

Comment: `adb shell "logcat -f /sdcard/logcat.log &"`

Comment: @AlexP. nothing happens (missing ">" ?). i added a redirection sign after the -f but the result is the same as in the post. a 0 byte file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to solve it is to create a bash script an push it into data/local/tmp folder, on most android devices there is no need to define the #!/system/bin/sh or #!/bin/bash in the first line.
The procedure is:

1)Create file with : logcat > /sdcard/logcat.txt &

2)adb push  /data/local/tmp

3)adb shell chmod +x /data/local/tmp/

4)adb shell /data/local/tmp/

Regards

Comment: exactly what i'v tried. but a file with a size of 0 bytes is created (/sdcard/logcat.txt) and it does't record anything.

Comment: Which phone brand do you have ?
1)Create file with : logcat > /sdcard/logcat.txt &

2)adb push /data/local/tmp

3)adb shell chmod +x /data/local/tmp/

4)adb shell /data/local/tmp/

Comment: Since the solution was working only on a vary small portion of the devices i've tested, i eventually resorted to building an open-connection Logcat logic (using JADB lib which was vary helpful). i've opened and closed connection streams when needed.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this method and it worked on my device

1. > adb shell
2. > logcat -f sdcard/logcat.txt &

OR

> adb shell logcat -f sdcard/logcat.txt &

Now you can remove your usb cable

Comment: hi, as said above, i am required to run it from an external cli command, meaning in a single lined adb command. if following your example "adb shell 'logcat -f sdcard/logcat.txt &' "would have worked, that'd be perfect. but it doesn't

Comment: but it is also working on my side adb shell logcat -f sdcard/logcat.txt &

Comment: i'v followed your command, but the connection remains open. assuming i close the connection (^C) and i still see in the shell that the file is increasing in size. once i disconnect the data cable, and reconnect it later, i see that the file size does not change.

Comment: when you reconnect the cable adb daemon restarts. that means you need to execute the above operations again.

Comment: if you execute adb shell and then logcat -f sdcard/logcat.txt & your problem will be solved. because it does not depends on adbd now. you can reconnect the usb and it won't stop

Comment: that ain't it, it still doesn't work for me on none of my devices (os 4.X - 6.X). it is probably a matter of sessions. but as i said so earlier, i need to accomplish it in a single line command, and not in two steps.